# AppEngine doesn't serve files with abnormal extensions

Tags: google-app-engine, app.yaml

I need to make a .data file available through a URL. Locally, this works perfectly, the app.yaml simply contains

```
- url: /dev
  static_dir: dev/
```

and everything in that folder is served correctly, .data .js and .html

On the server, the .data file is inaccessible. I've even tried specifically mentioning the files name

```
- url: /dev/WebGL/Release/WebGL.data
  mime_type: text/plain
  static_files: dev/WebGL/Release/WebGL.data
  upload: dev/WebGL/Release/WebGL.data
```

and it still won't serve.
you can see it live here

[tbc-pre-alpha.appspot.com/dev/WebGL/Release/WebGL.data](http://tbc-pre-alpha.appspot.com/dev/WebGL/Release/WebGL.data) <- inaccessible

[tbc-pre-alpha.appspot.com/dev/WebGL/Release/WebGL.js](http://tbc-pre-alpha.appspot.com/dev/WebGL/Release/WebGL.js) <- accessible

there's another file WebGL.html.mem that's not working for the same reasons

any help's much appreciated. thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just use the first example using /dev if that works correctly?  What are you trying to do? Thanks. :)

Comment: it works correctly locally on my computer, for some reason on the server it won't. Maybe I should add that the file is 64 mb - maybe app engine won't upload it because of its size or something?

Comment: I'm trying to make sure I understand your problem.

Comment: it works locally on my computer, when I do "goapp serve myapp", then try to access it via localhost:8080/dev/WebGL/Release/WebGL.data

but when deploying to the server (the url mentioned in the original post), it gives a 404. you say it works with other files though? I'll try smaller ones or different folders and see what happens

Comment: Check if it is uploaded in your console:
https://console.developers.google.com/project/ and then go to Source code -> Browse

Comment: Okay, so thanks to both your suggestions, I ran a bunch of experiments and it seems there's a hard limit of 32MB for files on app engine. according to the internets, the way to go around it is with blobstore, so I'll try that. thanks guys!

Comment: @AdamZeira you should self answer in the answers section below, and link to the documentation. Your question, and the answer, will then help others with the same problem.  Good luck and hope you find an alternative!

Comment: I'll figure out how to use the blobstore, and post an answer that includes that solution as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was that App Engine gives a hard limit of 32 MB per static file size ("No single static data file may be larger than 32MB." [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas))

The recommended solution was to use the blobstore, though in my specific case because I wanted only 1 static file that I upload, I found cloud storage to be more useful (console.developers.com -> Storage -> Cloud Storage), and then use the blobstore function BlobKeyForFile ([link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/blobstore/reference#BlobKeyForFile)) to send the file for people requesting the desired URL

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something is wrong with your urls, although it looks good. Try this:

```
- url: /(.*\.data)
  mime_type: text/plain
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.*\.data)
```

I am not sure which language you are using, but [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/appconfig) you should be able to find more info.

Comment: Hi Karens, welcome back to Stack Overflow.  If you [edit] your post to explain why this works, it will add even more value, not just for the op but also anyone else who has this same problem.  Hope this helps!

Comment: good idea, but no go :( same as before, works locally, but not on the server. I'm using Go, just to try it out, and the entire website is static files so it shouldn't matter, but I don't mind switching anyway